# TableView or ScrollView for edit form?

Tags: iphone, data-binding, editing

I wonder which will be the best route for build edit forms on the iPhone, using a TableView or using a scrollview.

I need:

- Support up to 15 fields (similar to contact app)
- The same behavior of safari forms, where is possible go back/forward among fields, and the form center the selected field and stay there when the user end the editing
- Simple layout (one field after other)

I'm looking for the most-user friendly experience. Which route has been proved to be the better?

Exist good examples of great edit forms on iPhone apps?

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for a tableview organized by sections. If nothing else, it is a more common layout and most users will be familiar with it.

In either case, you will have to handle the transition from field to field with custom code.